# Inline JS callback syntax Vs Internal JS callback syntax

Tags: javascript, html, browser, callback, attributes

Inline callback JS syntax looks like:

```
<h3 id="h3style" onMouseOver="changeColor();">     
      Rollover
</h3>
```

Internal callback JS syntax looks like:

```
<script>
     document.getElementById('h3style').onMouseOver = changeColor;
     function changeColor(){ } 
</script>
```

I understand that first syntax is evaluated by browser engine and second syntax is evaluated by JS engine.

But, Why html attribute `onMouseOver` has value as function call(with parenthesis) unlike second approach? Why html attribute syntax(`onMouseOver="changeColor;"`) is not allowed?

*Note: It is difficult to remember, two different syntax*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start by looking at the pure js version.

```
document.getElementById('h3style').onMouseOver = changeColor;
function changeColor(){ }
```

Now in this situation, assigning a function is the only thing that you are able to do. You could obviously assign something weird like a value, but that just amounts to the code doing nothing (no errors even). The point is that you cannot assign a variable "some javascript" to complete, you can only create a function that contains "some javascript". In other words you can't do this:

```
elem.onMouseOver = 'changeColor();'; // technically legal but does nothing (just assigns a string)
```

However javascript does have [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) which is able to execute string versions of javascript. For example:

```
eval('changeColor();');
```

---

So now to the DOM. When you assign something to an attribute, the thing on the right hand side is a string (not actual javascript). Because it is a string, behind the scenes the system is only able to do something like `eval()`.

The main takeaway point is that in the html case, the stuff you are writing inside the attribute is **not** javascript, but rather just a string. A string that gets evaluated at run time and converted into javascript.

---

Also to answer your final question: "Why html attribute `syntax(onMouseOver="changeColor;")` is not allowed?", well technically it is allowed. However it is equivalent to doing this in javascript:

```
onMouseOver = function(){
    eval('changeColor;');
}
```

Which clearly doesn't do a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the callback becomes this:

```
function onmouseover(event) {
  changeColor();
}
```

vs the second case the callback is just `changeColor`

Here is an example:

```html
<html>
<body>

<h3 id="test1" onClick="test1();">
      test1
</h3>

<h3 id="test2">
      test2
</h3>

<script>
  function test1() {
    console.log('test1');
  }

  function test2() {
    console.log('test2');
  }

  document.getElementById('test2').onclick = test2;

  console.log(document.getElementById('test1').onclick);
  console.log(document.getElementById('test2').onclick);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of [event handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) (not to be confused with [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener)).

- [Event handler IDL attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes).

  You can set them in JS by assigning a function reference to that property (also known as IDL attribute), e.g.

  ```
  myelement.onmyevent = myfunction;
  ```

  Note the property name is in lowercase.

  The assigned function function will be used as the event handler. When an event is dispatched, the function will be invoked as usual for JS functions, passing the event as the first argument, and the current event target as the `this` value.
- [Event handler content attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes)

  You can set them both in HTML or in JS through `setAttribute`. As for any attribute, its value must be a string.

  ```
  myelement.setAttribute("onMyEvent", "some code here");
  ```

  Note HTML attributes are case-insensitive.

  The event handler will be an [internal raw uncompiled handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler) consisting of the attribute's new value and the script location where the attribute was set to this value.

  When an event is dispatched, the browser will [get the current value of the event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler). Summarizing, that means:

  1. That string will be parsed as if it were a function body
  2. The scope of that function will be the global one, shadowed by the document, the form owner (if any) and the element (if any).

**TL;DR**: With event handler IDL attributes you must assign a function reference, and the browser will invoke it for you. With event handler content attributes you must assign a string, and the browser will wrap it in a function and will call it for you.